# Understanding a drill down tableview tutorial

Tags: ios, uitableview, drilldown

Im trying to follow this tutorial on http://jleeiii.blogspot.com/2012/01/uistoryboard-power-drill.html but being new to developing i'm not too sure how to complete it? Id be grateful if someone would be able to help me with the source code. basically I'm struggling with what classes i need and where to put the code.

thanks

Comment: Can I help you with any questions if you are still working on UIStoryBoards

Comment: Update, see requested sample: http://jleeiii.blogspot.com/2012/05/uistoryboard-power-drill-batteries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to follow http://www.raywenderlich.com/ site. It is a great source of tutorials to begin iOS developments. Their tutorials are useful and they provide a step by step tutorial. For storyboard, I suggest you to follow http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

David

Comment: I have flowed this tutorial but just trying to relate it to the tutorial i mentioned I'm struggling with.